# Updating a friend list in my database

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have been storing the friend list using the following database structure:

User Id | Friend Id

My problem is that I have an interface that lets them add/delete users from the friend list and the friend list should get saved upon hit.

So would it make sense that I delete all the friends for that user Id and then repopulate the database with the saved friend list ? Sounds a bit counterproductive because if a user adds just one more user, it would be deleting all the friends and re-adding them all.

Comment: Why don't you just insert or delete a row in the table when needed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can delete all and then repopulate or you can store the initial state of the list of friends, then compare with the final list after user edit.

I recommend you use this function [array_diff($array1, $array2)](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php), doing something like:

```
$initial_list = array (1,2,3,4,5);
$list_after_edit = array (1,2,5,6);

$all_new_items = array_diff($list_after_edit,$initial_list);
foreach ($all_new_items as $item) {
    // Add to database this item
}

$all_deleted_items = array_diff($initial_list,$list_after_edit);
// Execute this query:
$query = 'DELETE FROM table WHERE `User Id` = <some ID> AND `Friend Id` in (' . implode(',',$all_deleted_items) . ')';
```